# How to start user procedure in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server function which I need to exec. But I tried to call it via select, exec - it throws an error. How to fix that bug and launch that function?

Procedure code

```
create or alter function mergetext
    (@TitleOfCourtesy text, 
     @FirstName text, 
     @LastName text)
returns varchar(255)
as
begin
    return concat(@TitleOfCourtesy, ' ', @FirstName, ' ', @LastName)
end

select mergetext('a','b','c')
```

Error message

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure mergetext, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure mergetext, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
> 'mergetext' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Add `GO` after the procedure definition. Or run them as separate batches. Do you really want to add three `text` values to form a `varchar(255)` though.

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is not [procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It's a [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
Second, the [text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) type is deprecated and should not be used.
Then, you need to separate the creation of the object either using `GO`, executing it in a separate query window or selecting only the function and pressing F5.

Try this:

```
create or alter function mergetext(
    @TitleOfCourtesy text, 
    @FirstName text, 
    @LastName text
)
returns varchar(255)
as
begin
    return concat(@TitleOfCourtesy,' ',@FirstName,' ',@LastName)
end

GO

select dbo.mergetext('a','b','c')
```

and finally, why you are creating a wrapper of the `CONCAT` function. Just use the `CONCAT` wherever you need.

Comment: No, it not work. This code throws Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure mergetext, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
'mergetext' is not a recognized built-in function name. error

Comment: @who_am_i Just specify the schema like this `select dbo.mergetext('a','b','c')`

Answer (score 1):

When calling a SQL Server function, you need to include the schema. If you did not specify a schema when creating the function, then the function is created using your default schema (probably dbo). So try calling the function so:
`SELECT dbo.mergetext('a','b','c')`